# How to get email notification from jenskin when a build is failed?

Tags: ant, jenkins

I have made a project and i am trying to build it by jenskin. I am invoking ant script. when any build fails, i want it to send mail to every person who is resposible for failure.

in the project configuration, i am adding email notification in post build option. in console, it shows email sent to "email-id" but i dont receive any email.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you try the suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure Global setting if you haven't done it already. Go to `Jenkins > Configure > E-mail Notification`. Follow the steps mentioned [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GMail) and configure the same as per your set up.

You should also check [Email-ext](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) plugin which offers many more options to configure.

Comment: Can you tell me how would i know my SMTP server as it is a company email account which is outlook.

Comment: You can ask your IT guys. Check if this [link](http://wiki.bizagi.com/en/index.php?title=Find_SMTP_Server_in_Outlook) helps

Answer (score 0):

yes.. I found the answer.. you just need to set the "System Admin e-mail address" in manage_jenkins->configure system->jenkins location